# Is this scenario true (too long to write in question)?

Tags: thermodynamics, explosions, shock-waves

Imagine I were to lock myself in a 1×1×3 (meters) box.
And this box was made of some newly discovered material which was `projectile-proof` (bullet proof), could fully absorb any shockwave and was resistant to all levels of heat, disallowing heat to enter the box.

Now assuming someone detonated `100 megatonnes` of TNT about `1 meter` from the box, and due to the box's material, it was left unscratched and unmoved.

Could the same be said for me in the box?
Would the TNT affect me in anyway?
Since I don't think we have such material, this is all speculation. I just want to know what you'd think.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking about what happens in a physically impossible situation (*"resistant to all levels of heat"*,*"fully absorb any shockwave"*).

Comment: @ACuriousMind - At least tell me why it's impossible so I can learn something I didn't know. Don't just deem it usless and leave me with false knowledge.

Comment: The problem is that to answer the question we would need to know the details about this magical material. Otherwise you're just listing properties that nothing we know can have and then asking how it would work; well, the answer is that no one has a clue.

Comment: @Javier - Ahhhh right I see. My bad haha. Kind of an aimless question I guess.

Comment: *"I just want to know what you'd think."* - Your imaginary material conflicts with known physical law so what imaginary physical model would you like us to use to answer your question?

Comment: @Alfred Centauri - Let's assume the material is resistant to the heat produced by 100 megatonnes of TNT (so not all levels of heat). And resistant to a shockwave with high amplitude (same produced by 100 megatonnes of TNT).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have asked that the box be made of some material of infinite stiffness, which is prohibited by relativity-the speed of sound in the material would be infinite-but let's play along.  The pressure of the explosion would not be transmitted into the box, so you would be fine from that standpoint.  As the box is a thermal insulator, the heat of the explosion would also not be a problem.

Your problem is the pressure wave generated by the explosion would be enough to literally blow the box away.  It would accelerate rapidly, throwing you against the wall of the box violently.

In the spirit of the question, you could imagine anchoring the box to a large mass like the earth using the same magic material.  Then you would be fine until you suffocated.

A similar question is explored in [Larry Niven's story Neutron Star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutron_Star_(short_story)).  General Products spacecraft hulls were supposed to be impervious to all outside influences....

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly the answer I was looking for.

Comment: I imagine it would actually be a toss-up between whether he suffocates or dies of heat stroke first. His body heat can't escape the box, either.